# Mysql RegExp question selecting from a list of codes

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to match a list of motorcycle models to a series of ebay codes for listing motorcycles in ebay.

So we get a motorcycle model name that will be something like:

XL883C Sportster where the manufacturer is Harley Davidson

I have a list of ebay codes that look like this

```
MB-100-0    Other
MB-100-1            883
MB-100-2            1000
MB-100-3            1130
MB-100-4            1200
MB-100-5            1340
MB-100-6            1450
MB-100-7            Dyna
MB-100-8            Electra
MB-100-9            FLHR
MB-100-10   FLHT
MB-100-11   FLSTC
MB-100-12   FLSTR
MB-100-13   FXCW
MB-100-14   FXSTB
MB-100-15   Softail
MB-100-16   Sportster
MB-100-17   Touring
MB-100-18   VRSCAW
MB-100-19   VRSCD
MB-100-20   VRSCR
```

So I want to match the model name against the list above using a regExp pattern.

I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT modelID FROM tblEbayModelCodes WHERE
LOWER(makeName) = 'harley-davidson' AND fnmodel REGEXP '[883|1000|1130|1200|1340|1450|Dyna|Electra|FLHR|FLHT|FLSTC|FLSTR|FXCW|FXSTB|Softail|Sportster|Touring|VRSCAW|VRSCD|VRSCR].*' LIMIT 1
```

however when I run the query I would expect the code to match on either MB-100-1     for 883 or MB-100-16 for Sportster but when I run it the query returns MB-100-0 for Other.

I am guessing that I have the pattern incorrect, so can anybody suggest what I might need to do to correct this?

Many thanks
Graham

Comment: Side note: `LOWER()` should not be really necessary if your column uses the proper collation.

Answer (score 0):

[chars] matches any of the characters 'c','h','a','r','s'

So by giving it such a long list, it will inevitably match just the first item (single character)

Try this instead

```
LOWER(makeName) = 'harley-davidson' AND fnmodel REGEXP '(883|1000|1130|1200|1340|1450|Dyna|Electra|FLHR|FLHT|FLSTC|FLSTR|FXCW|FXSTB|Softail|Sportster|Touring|VRSCAW|VRSCD|VRSCR).*' LIMIT 1
```

You might also consider **not** using REGEX and using [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) instead.

Comment: Richard, I have tried the following code 

Because I am trying to run this as a function I decided to run the query independantly.

SET @fnModel = 'XL883C Sportster';
SELECT
 modelID
FROM
 tblEbayModelCodes
WHERE
 LOWER(makeName) = 'harley-davidson' AND 
 @fnModel REGEXP'(Dyna|Electra|FLHR|FLHT|FLSTC|FLSTR|FXCW|FXSTB|Softail|Sportster|Touring|VRSCAW|VRSCD|VRSCR).*'

The resultset is actually all ebay codes that are tagged as 'harley-davidson' so limiting the list only returns the first in the list hence 'MB-100-0'  so its not actually pattern matching the string.

Any clues?

Comment: @Graham - you're matching REGEXP to your @fnModel, which will match due to XL883C **Sportster**? Since it is a variable, it is a match "for all rows", regardless of the records's fnModel column. LIMIT 1 then takes the first one..

Comment: Hi Richard, I understand, so when used in a function, I want to pass in a string as an in parameter which I have represented as 'XL883C Sportster'.  I then want to perform some pattern matching against it against the table that holds all the ebay modelIDs and modelNames.  Its the modelName field I want to search on, (apologies for not being clear).  So I want to return the MB-100-16 modelID for matching against the modelName 'sportster'.  Any thoughts on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Not really fully tested, but it should be something like this:

```
REGEXP '^MB-[0-9]+-[0-9]+[[:space:]]+(883|1000|1130|1200|1340|1450|Dyna|Electra|FLHR|FLHT|FLSTC|FLSTR|FXCW|FXSTB|Softail|Sportster|Touring|VRSCAW|VRSCD|VRSCR)$'
```

In detail:

```
^MB-            Starts with MB-
[0-9]+          One or more digits
-               Dash
[0-9]+          One or more digits
[[:space:]]+    One or more white space
(883|1000|...)$ Ends with one of these
```

Here's the reference for the regexp dialect spoken by MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

**Answer to comment:**

If you want to match the *Sportster* row them remove all other conditions. And you may not even need regular expressions:

```
WHERE fnmodel LIKE '% Sportster'
```

Comment: Hi Alvaro, I think I need to explain a little better.  I want the resultset to equal MB-100-16, so I need to search for the word 'Sportster' in the input string 'XL883C Sportster'.